# C# database in client machine

Tags: c#, database

I want to know how I can use a local database on the machine of the client. I can connect a local SQL database in my computer but I need to know how every client can have an own local database on his computer. The database is for saving changes in a DataGridView.

For example, I had a SQL Local Database connected to my DataGridView and everything was good but the Visual Studio compels me to save the database on my computer.

Comment: Is this a windows application or a web application?

Comment: Please clarify this: **Visual Studio compels me to save the database on my computer**

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876).  It will require each client to install this, but you can include those requirements in your installer, and the SQL Server Compact Edition is free.

Comment: Not supported directly in Visual Studio past 2010. I believe [SQL Server local DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) is now the "supported" option in newer Visual Studios.

Comment: @afufa123 build an installer and deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several good, free databases out their.

- Microsoft SQL Server Express
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle's MySQL
- MariaDB
- Apache Derby
- Firebird SQL

You did state in your question you have a local SQL database you connect to on your machine. If thats what you are using to build your program it wouldn't be a bad idea to set up client machines similar.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE or SQLite are both useful because you could package them with your application, provided this is a client app and not a web app.

There is no install and they can be used directly by referencing the assembly and won't require your client to install additional software.